# Breaking String

Tags: iphone

I have to break this string in two parts: 2º Felipe Massa (BRA)

```
1)2
2)Felipe Massa (BRA)
```

I am using this method

```
myArray = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@"º"];
```

but its not breaking it, and returning me this: `1\U00ba Felipe Massa (BRA)`

I know that this a Unicode character, but how can I break it? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
NSString* blah = @"2º Felipe Massa (BRA)";
NSLog(@"%@", [blah componentsSeparatedByString:@"\u00ba"]);
```

You have to use the unicode escape sequence to make this work.

Comment: I tried it, but XCODE saya "Incomplete UNICODE String", may be because "\" is an escape character. I tried even ['componentsSeparatedByString:@"\\u00ba"], still not working :-(